# ValidationError - ошибка 400 вместо сообщения

Tags: python, django, валидация, django-rest-framework

Сделал регистрацию пользователя через drf. Но я хочу сделать подтверждение пароля (2 раза ввод).

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password", "profile", 'confirm_password')

    def validate(self, data):
        password = data['password']
        confirm_pass = data['confirm_password']
        if password != confirm_pass:
             raise serializers.ValidationError("НЕ ТО!")
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password('password')
        user.save()
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user
```

Если ввожу одинаковые пароли, то регистрация проходит успешно, принтами выводятся пароли, а если разные - то raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords do not match") возвращает ошибку 400 без какой-либо подсказки. Как вызывать подсказку?

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: добавьте код `view`

Comment: там все слишком коротко, добавил. а прилетает все из шаблона посредством vue и axios

Answer (score 0):

Можно переопределить метод `create` для `UserViewSet`:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: если я правильно понял, то у меня проблема не с джанго. нужно писать валидаторы и сообщения в темплеите, т.к. форма полностью написала на vue. ее и надо допиливать.